# CSS: How to remove space between image and border?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a CSS image with a box-shadow effect on hover, but why is there space between the border and my image? How can I remove this? Thank you

This is my hover effect with box-shadow

[image: click to open the image]

this is my css code:

```
.hover-zoom:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.05);
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0px 8px 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hover-zoom {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-box{
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

this is my react-js code:

```
 <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <div className="img-box">
          <img src={earth} width="85%" height="85%" className="hover-zoom" />
        </div>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
```

Thanks if you can solve this!

Comment: Cannot replicate - please provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YzZLmqw

Comment: You are probably using an image that has margin/spacing/border in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what spacing you are talking about. If this is related with the black border appeared after the transform, you can play with the [transform box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)

```
transform-box: fill-box
```